# Best way to start a background process from GCP HTTP function call?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

So, according to the docs here https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http

> Terminating HTTP functions
> If a function creates background tasks (such as threads, futures, Node.js Promise objects, callbacks, or system processes), you must terminate or otherwise resolve these tasks before returning an HTTP response. Any tasks not terminated prior to an HTTP response may not be completed, and may also cause undefined behavior.

So, if one needs to launch a long-running background task from within HTTP function, but still return from function fast, there is no a straightforward way.

Have tried the PubSub approach (calling await topic.publishJSON(pars)), but looks like publishing a topic is quite time-consuming operation - which takes 2-3 secs. (8-)

Then probably pubsub trigger function runs well ok, but this 2-3 seconds delay makes it useless.

P.S.: using the approach with starting Promise from inside function is actually working, but it sounds like error-prone since it's against the docs.

Comment: Have you considered writing the request to Firestore/RTDB and trigger the background task from that?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a quick answer you have 2 type of solutions

**Async**

- With Cloud Functions, you need to invoke (perform an HTTP call) another functions (or Cloud Run or App Engine), without waiting the answer, and answer back to the requester. The call that you performed will run in background and answer something to your cloud function that no longer listen!
- With PubSub, it's similar. Instead of invoking a Cloud Functions (or Cloud Run or App Engine), you publish a message into a PubSub topic. Then create a subscription to call your long running pocess
- Same idea with Cloud Task, but you create a Task in a queue

**Sync**

- If you use Cloud Run instead of Cloud Functions, you are able to perform partial answer to the requester. Like that, you can immediately answer back to the requester with a partial response which says "OK" and continue the process in the request context, and send another partial response when you want, or at the end of the long running process to inform the user the end of their process.

Comment: Many thanks for giving me 4 different ideas. Async method #2 with PubSub - as you see this is what I've tried already. And the timing is not good at all. Concerning method #1 - all my functions are callables, so not sure it's feasible, also you have to dispose "long-runnning" piece of code as a function (just for the purpose of calling it from another function), plus you have limits like 300sec max timeout. About Cloud Run - looks interesting - just investigating it. Will update.